# Build failed by schemaExport, HelloWorld program with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I am new in Hibernate and try to write my first "helloworld" program. I am using the step in the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate". as I run the `build.xml` with ant I become the following error. The error came as a schema have to be generate to on the database using hbm2ddl

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\mypath\build.xml:60: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: >org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4/im/StaticLoggerBinder;
>
> "schemaexport target von build.xml(so sieht die stelle wo der fehler sein sollte aus)"
>
> Translation: "schemaexport target of build.xml(the have to be here, but i cannot found it!)"

```
<target name="schemaexport" depends="compile, copymetafiles"
description="Exports a generated schema to DB and file">
<hibernatetool destdir="${basedir}">
<classpath path="${build.dir}"/>
<configuration
configurationfile="${build.dir}/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
<hbm2ddl
drop="true"
create="true"
export="true"
outputfilename="helloworld-ddl.sql"
delimiter=";"
format="true"/>
</hibernatetool>
</target>
```

I have the following *.jar file in my workdir/lib directory:

```
antlr.jar
asm.jar
asm-attrs.jars
c3p0.jar
cglib.jar
commons-collections.jar
jcl-over-slf4j.jar
dom4j.jar
hibernate3.jar
hsqldb.jar
jta.jar
```

---

thank for reply! I very appreciate.
I am using the latest version of slf4j(slf4j-api-1.6.1). This version come with the hibernate I downloaded, hibernate-distribution-3.6.5.Final, and was located in the folder lib/required of this hibernate version. I also have the following library(jar file):
all ends with .jar
dom4j-1.6.1
hibernate3
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final
hibernate-tools
hsqldb
javassist-3.12.0.GA
jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.4(I also try commons-logging-1.1.1 but nothing change)
jta-1.1
log4j-1.2.16
slf4j-api-1.6.1

Any other idea?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a version problem: you're using a wrong version of the slf4j library. One of the libraries you're using tries to lookup a certain method, but that method doesn't exist in the version of the library you are using.

Check which version exactly you need by looking in the documentation of the version of Hibernate or other libraries you are using (or try the latest version from [slf4j.org](http://www.slf4j.org/)).